# indexing in loops: var[x+1] subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I'm creating and storing a bunch of conditional matrices in vector form then I'm recalling them, returning their structure to matrix, and multiplying by a vector. This vector depends on the previous vector and the current matrix. I have tried to express this in the second loop as [,y+1] to index the vectors on the output matrix . While I get the desire result, I also get an error that aborts the program. I would appreciate suggestions on how to approach this.

```
env=rnorm(50, 22, 5)
les=matrix(nrow=9,ncol=length(env),byrow=T)
for (x in 1:length(env))
{
    a=sqrt(env[x])-3
    b=sqrt(env[x])-2        
    c=sqrt(env[x])-1
    A=.9
    B=.5
    C=.2

les[,x]=c(a,b,c,A,0,0,0,B,0)
}   
pop=matrix(nrow=3,ncol=length(env))
pop[,1]=c(1,2,2)
for (y in 1:length(env))
{

    pop[,y+1]=pop[,y]%*%matrix(les[,y],3,3,T)
}           
print(pop)  
barplot(pop)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vector, matrix and array subscripting in R is all 1-based. You need to iterate only up to `length(env)-1` if you are going to regerence ahead by 1 inside the loop.

Comment: I see what you are saying but I cant get rid of it by shortening the loop. The error seems to be related to my referencing.   "Error in pop[, y + 1] = pop[, y] %*% matrix(les[, y], 3, 3, T) : 
    subscript out of bounds"

Comment: You are having problems in your attempt to shorten the loop related to operator precedence. You should be using for `(y in 1:(length(env)-1) )` rather than `for (y in 1:length(env)-1 )`.

Comment: Oh yes. Much appreciated DWin.